# curl multi interface program with progress meter

Tags: c++, libcurl

I came across this example that demonstrates curl multi interface to download a single file.
[curl multi single](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/multi-single.html). I have added this code to my program. My requirement is as follows.

1. I want to download and upload a file, and while the file is being downloaded/uploaded, I want the average upload/download rate to be displayed on the screen.
2. I was initially using curl easy interface with a single call to `curl_easy_perform`. Since this is synchronous/blocking, I was not able to get the screen update thread update the rate on the screen.

This is my drive to switch to curl multi interface.(as it is not blocking) After switching to curl multi interface too I find that screen update is not happening. Is curl multi interface expected to help in my situation. Are there any other solutions that you can suggest.

This is the relevant portion of my code.

```
      curl_multi_add_handle(m_multiCurl, m_curl);
      curl_multi_perform(m_multiCurl, &stillRunning);

      while(stillRunning) {
        CURLMcode mc;
        int numFds;
        mc = curl_multi_wait(m_multiCurl, NULL, 0, 1000, &numFds);
        if(mc != CURLM_OK) {
                m_logger->errorf("curl_multi_wait() failed, code %d.\n", mc);
                break;
        }
        if(!numFds) {
             repeats++;
             if(repeats > 1) {
                 WAITMS(100);
             }
        } else {
             repeats = 0;
        }
        curl_multi_perform(m_multiCurl, &stillRunning);
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly counter-intuitively, you need to set [CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS.html) per easy handle (to zero) to get the progress meter output *per easy handle* to occur. See example below.

**But**, and this is I think a fairly important but, when you do more than one transfer concurrently outputting the built-in progress meter per-transfer is probably *not* what you want.

When doing more than one transfer at any one time, I would imagine that what you want to do is to implement the [CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION.html) callback and implement your own progress meter that can show the progress for all transfers at the same time in a nice way.

CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS example:

```
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");

  /* enable progress meter */
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 0L);

  /* Perform the request */
  curl_easy_perform(curl);
}
```